# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in Web API 2 doesn't work with CORS

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-5, cors, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I'm developing a website using ASP.NET MVC5 and WEB API 2.2. In my web api controller, I have an if condition to check if user is logged in:

```
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return BadRequest("NotLoggedIn");
    }
```

This works fine for if there's no "www" in front of my domain name. But it will return `BadRequest("NotLoggedIn")` if "www" Is added to my domain name. For example, my domain is example.com. If user type www.example.com, the webpage will make an AJAX request to example.com/api/controller, and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will return false. It will return ture if user just enter example.com.

I have enabled CORS in the global level:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.example.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried with http instead of www directly?  So something like _http_://www_.example.com_ without the undescores

Comment: I added the underscore above because the formatter in html will remove the http and the www parts of the url, so remove them and try since just www is not a valid url it needs http.

Comment: Hi Omar, all my ajax request url has http in the front

Comment: Before you do anything,  add http to this EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*"

Comment: Hi Omar, I did added http in the EnableCorsAttribute. I just forgot to type it in. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

I need to decorate the api controller with:

```
[EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.example.com" , "*", "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
```